# Creating a parametrised, MySQL query with wildcards

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to populate a datagrid using a parameter based query.  However, I want to have the ability to enter multiple parameters that may contain wildcards.  However, the following test query isn't correct.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

```
SELECT `Customer ID`, `Company Name`, `Address Line 3` FROM XTest.all WHERE `Company Name` LIKE '%'+@Company+'%' ORDER BY `Company Name`;
```

Comment: What do you mean by *params may contain wild cards*?

Comment: I want to find everything that has an "A" in the field, so you would normally do LIKE %a% - but this query is using parameters.

Comment: *Using parameters* means?

Comment: It's a safer way of running a query as opposed to just accepting the string.  For example if the string contains " - it may throw an error.

Comment: Ok. You are talking about Prepared Statements.

Comment: OK - Thank you - any idea how to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose column names in `""` double quotes (depends on the setting of SQL Mode).

> Please check this link and follow the answer of @DRapp.
>   Here is link: [mysql parameterized query in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20520279/mysql-parameterized-query-in-asp-net)

As per the answer you need to use `?` instead of `@`.

Try this:

```
SELECT `Customer ID`, `Company Name`, `Address Line 3` 
        FROM XTest.all 
        WHERE `Company Name` LIKE  concat('%',? + "Company",'%') 
        ORDER BY `Company Name`;

objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Company", "CompanyValue");
```

Comment: sorry yes not applicable for mysql.

Comment: Thanks Hassan for the effort (much appreciated)

Comment: Really sorry - but still don't understand.  It would be really appreciated if you could apply your solution to the query.  thank you (again).

Comment: @HassanNisar: `@` being part of the variable is not an error.

Comment: Thank you so much - that's a real help.

Answer (score 2):

```
string company = "%" + your_criteria_on_company + "%";

string sql = "SELECT 
                `Customer ID`, `Company Name`, `Address Line 3` 
              FROM XTest.all 
              WHERE 
                `Company Name` LIKE @Company 
              ORDER BY `Company Name`";

SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand( sql, dbConnection );
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@Company", company );

' add more of your code here
' and then
sqlCommand.Prepare();
MySqlDataReader resultSet = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

**Refer to**:

- Documentation on [SqlParameter AddWithValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)
- [Using Prepared Statement in C# with Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070434/using-prepared-statement-in-c-sharp-with-mysql)