# Inserting values into foreign Key MySQLCommand C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, database

I been trying different things to get my code to work.

I'm pretty new with both c# and with DB. But the thing is i am trying to fix a db for a Music event where i add in band names and there members.

I have 2 tables. One with Band and one with Band Members. I am using MySQLCommand in visual studio C#

My button code for the insertion of code to a MySQL Class

```
    private void bt_LäggTill_Band_Medlem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySql mySQL = new MySql();
        MySqlConnection myConn = mySQL.GetServer();
       // string insert = @"Insert Into BandMedlemar(BNamn , MedlemsNamn)Values ('" + cb_Band_Medlemar.Text.ToString() + "',(Select BNamn from Band Where BNamn = '" + cb_Band_Namn.Text.ToString() + "'))";
    //    string insert = "Insert Into BandMedlemar(MedlemsNamn , BNamn) Select val.MedlemsNamn , f.BNamn from (Values ('" + cb_Band_Medlemar.Text.ToString() + "','" + cb_Band_Namn.Text.ToString() + "')) val(MedlemsNamn,BNamn) Left Join Band f Useing (BNamn)";
        string insert = 
            "Insert Into BandMedlemar(MedlemsNamn , BNamn) " +
        "Select '" + cb_Band_Medlemar.Text.ToString() + "' , BNamn " +
        "From Band Where BNamn='" + cb_Band_Namn.Text.ToString() + "'";
        int count = 1;
        string para = cb_Band_Medlemar.Text.ToString().Replace(" ", "");
        string para2 =cb_Band_Medlemar.Text.ToString();
        mySQL.Insert(myConn, insert, count, para, para2);
        Update();
    }
```

I tried a couple things i let them be there.

and then there is my SQL code that takes the data end sends in to the database

```
    public void Insert(MySqlConnection myConn , string text , int count , string para , string para2)
    {
        try
        {
            myConn.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(text, myConn);
            //cmd.Connection = myConn;
            //cmd.CommandText = text;
            cmd.Prepare();
            string[] splited = para.Split('@');
            string[] splited2 = para2.Split('@');
            int number = 0;
            while (count != 0)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + splited[number], splited2[number]);
                count--;
                number++;
            }
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myConn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            myConn.Close();
        }
    }
```

the code works with normal insert with multiple parameters as well.

for more info i post my Create table for the band members

```
CREATE TABLE BandMedlemar 
( BNamn varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',MedlemsNamn varchar(30) NOT NULL, 
  Info varchar(50) default NULL, PRIMARY KEY (BNamn), 
  CONSTRAINT BandMedlemar_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (BNamn) REFERENCES Band (BNamn) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

As Primary key foreign key relationship is there, please help me how i could be able to add more then one member of a band

Please give me the proper solution as i am not getting it.

Comment: Send your error description. Uniqueness is usually a matter of Primary Key, not Foreign key

Comment: With the current code i'm getting
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Duplicate entry 'Iron Maiden' for key 1

Comment: The other error i'm getting in my tryes are
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ad4855/BandMedlemar`, CONSTRAINT `BandMedlemar_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`BNamn`) REFERENCES `Band` (`BNamn`))

Comment: Remove primary key from BNamn - (PRIMARY KEY (BNamn)) , Anyway you it is defaulted to '' and you will get PK violation in you will insert empty names

Comment: Offtopic: There is no need to add `ToString()` to `Text` (`Text.ToString()`). Text member is already a string.

Comment: are we talking about the BNamn in BandMedlemar or in the Band Becouse BandMedlemar.BNamn is foreign key to Band.BNamn.

Comment: oh realy thx i486 thought i needed to put it as string :s

Comment: HEre's an example with parameters and the MySqlConnection http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167924/c-sharp-with-mysql-insert-parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BNamn is the primary key in the BandMedlemmar-table.
Change the primary key to PRIMARY KEY (BNamn, MedlemsNamn) and try again.

And please do not concatenate strings to build SQL, you will get hacked. Use the parameters instead.

Comment: i know that thats why im useing the Parameters.AddWithValue. But are you saying its not good enough?

Comment: No you put placeholders in the sql that gets replaced with the parameters automatically. (I don't know the exact syntax for you MySql library.)

Comment: Oki if i understand this correct i put the code in and use that and the i get hackt with that and after that the parameters get in but that is to late right? becouse i thought the code didnt get sent to the db untill the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: Gp with what you have now and see if a new primary key solves your first problem.

Comment: yup works like a charm thank you for that. But im still a bit worryed with the other you said tho