# MYSQL SQL syntax error c#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have an error in my SQL statement. 
This is the query:

```
 MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into bills (bill_Number,bill_Date,bill_From,bill_Note,bill_TaxRate,bill_DisRate,bill_EntryDate,cus_Sup,by,archived) values(" + txbBillNumber.Text + ",'" + DateTime.Parse(txbBillDate.Text).Year + "-" + DateTime.Parse(txbBillDate.Text).Month + "-" + DateTime.Parse(txbBillDate.Text).Day + "'," + sup_Id + ",'" + txb_Note.Text + "'," + taxRate + "," + disRate + ",'" + DateTime.Now.Year + "-" + DateTime.Now.Month + "-" + DateTime.Now.Day + "'," + Bills.cus_Sup + ",0,0)", objConn);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

And in this image the error and the bills table structure:
[image: Screebshot1]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem is that the word **by** that you use as a column is a [reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) (both in MySQL and the SQL standard in general). To use it you have to enclose it in backticks `` or double-quotes " ".

Also, the string values need to be between single-quotes where applicable, but I think you got that.

On a side note you should look into using parametrized queries instead of concatenating. See this question for an example: [C# with MySQL INSERT parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167924/c-sharp-with-mysql-insert-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

Your string values must be enclosed in quotes in the SQL statement, like this:
`MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into bills (bill_Number,bill_Date,bill_From,bill_Note,bill_TaxRate,bill_DisRate,bill_EntryDate,cus_Sup,by,archived) values(\"" + txbBillNumber.Text + "\"...`

Answer (score 0):

My first thoughts is that "by" is a reserved word, and "by" needs to be encapsulated in single/double quotes...whatever mysql requires.  This is from sql server experience.