# MySQL Insert Operation fails with syntax error

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

Today I wanted to write a Code that scans all files in the "Documents" Folder of the User, takes the Text and the Filenames and puts them into a database(just as some kind of test if I could do that, not for getting data). But if it Inserts the content into the database, my program says there is a syntax error with the text in the files in my Documents Folder.

My Code:

```cs
using System;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.IO;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void
        Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Getting Connection ...");

            var datasource = @"localhost";//your server
            var database = "database"; //your database name
            var username = "username"; //username of server to connect
            var password = "password"; //password

            //your connection string 
            string connStr = $"Server={datasource};Database={database};Uid={username};Pwd={password}";
            //create instanace of database connection
            using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Openning Connection ...");

                    //open connection
                    conn.Open();

                    Console.WriteLine("Connection successful!");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
                }
                string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
                var txtFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*");
                foreach (string currentFile in txtFiles)
                {
                    string currentfile_txt = File.ReadAllText(currentFile);
                    var stm = $"INSERT INTO file_contents(File_Name, File_Content) VALUES ({currentFile}, {currentfile_txt});";
                    var cmd = new MySqlCommand(stm, conn);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

But if I run it, it gives me this Error:

> Unhandled exception. MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':\Users\49176\Documents\aaa.txt, )' at line 1

It seems like it handles the text in the aaa.txt as SQL Code.
How can I change that? (btw: In the txt file are just some random letters)

I hope you can help me

Comment: you should switch to prepared statements with parameters see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167924/c-sharp-with-mysql-insert-parameters , so that your  data is entered correctly and sql injection proof

Comment: If the answer is satisfactory, just accept it. Questions without answers don't bring value because other users never know if the answer is correct and they can use it for their purpose.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is missing quotes

```
var stm = $"INSERT INTO file_contents(File_Name, File_Content) 
            VALUES ('{currentFile}', '{currentfile_txt}');";
```

But better to do this

```cs
var stm = $"INSERT INTO file_contents(File_Name, File_Content) VALUES (@1, @2);";
var cmd = new MySqlCommand(stm, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", "temp")
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", "temp")

foreach (string currentFile in txtFiles)
{
    cmd.Parameters[0].Value = currentFile;
    cmd.Parameters[1].Value = File.ReadAllText(currentFile);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```